# node js if-else condition returning empty response

Tags: node.js

I am using **NodeJS** for my server side logic.I have following kind of scenerio:

```
var arr=[];
var array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];//array with some values.not empty
for(var i in array) {
  (function(i) {
    if(array[i]<7) {
      if(array[i]<4) {
        arr.push(array[i]);//1,2,3 in arr
      } else {
        arr.push(array[i]);//4,5,6 in arr
      }
    } else {//when i is las index if condition false out and runs this block
      if(i==array.length-1) {
        console.log(arr);//there should be 1,2,3,4,5,6 in arr but its empty
      }
    }
  }(i)) 
}
```

Now,i am expecting *arr* with some values which are definitely assigned in if and nested if blocks but this comes empty in outer else part.

Is there anything m doing wrong with nodeJS???

Comment: If both of your conditions test true then `arr` will contain values yes. I am not quite clear what you are doing with that else loop though.

Comment: there is a loop outside  if else block.at some iterations in loop "if" part will be executed at some "else" will b executed.if at the last iteration "else" part is executed array which have values from previous iterations will be empty.

Comment: It might be helpful to either create a JSFiddle for this or to put some working values. If I change your conditions (1 & 2) to pass for the first array value and fail for the second (and I have 2 values in array) then your else loops prints out an array with just the first value in it which sounds like what you are expecting.

Comment: yes i need this but i am getting empty array.let me put some dummy data to clear the scenerio.